# Dicionário executando todas as chaves ao invés de apenas uma

Tags: python, python-3.x

Eu tenho no código a seguir eu tenho uma função que executa determinada operação de acordo com os parâmetros passados. Em seguida, tenho um dicionário servindo como switch case, que servirá para definir quais parâmetros serão passados para a função.

```
def calculate(number, operator):
    for i in range(1, 11): print(eval(number + operator + str(i)))


inputs = list(input().split())

switch = {
    '1': calculate(inputs[0], '+'),
    '2': calculate(inputs[0], '*'),
    '3': calculate(inputs[0], '/'),
    '4': calculate(inputs[0], '-'),
}

switch[inputs[1]]
```

Mas ao executar o programa e escolher as entradas o programa executa todas as operações dentro do dicionário e não apenas aquela selecionada pelo usuário. Por exemplo, se as entradas forem 5 e 1, ao invés de apenas efetuar a operação de adição, temos a seguinte saída:

```
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
5
10
15
20
25
30
35
40
45
50
5.0
2.5
1.6666666666666667
1.25
1.0
0.8333333333333334
0.7142857142857143
0.625
0.5555555555555556
0.5
4
3
2
1
0
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
```

Alguém poderia me explicar o porquê disso e como consertar o problema?

Comment: 5 1, desta maneira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A construção no `switch` que tem chama as funções à medida que define os vários valores possíveis, o que lhe faz executar logo as 4 operações existentes.

Pode corrigir isso facilmente fazendo com que o `switch` apenas construa o valor que quer utilizar na função, e chama a função com esse novo valor:

```
import ast

def calculate(number, operator):
    for i in range(1, 11): print(ast.literal_eval(number + operator + str(i)))


inputs = list(input().split())

switch = { #apenas constroi os valores de correspondencia
    '1': '+',
    '2': '*',
    '3': '/',
    '4': '-',
}

calculate(inputs[0], switch[inputs[1]]) #chama com o valor que vem do switch
```

Saida:

```
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/ckE1KF)

**Nota**: Deve utilizar `ast.literal_eval` em vez de `eval` por questões de segurança, uma vez que lhe vai dar erro em vários tipos de chamadas, como por exemplo comandos no sistema operativo, que podem ser devastadores.